# AWS lambda producing `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found on native library call

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I keep getting the below error when I load native library in `AWS lambda`

```
/tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so)
```

I have read it's related to difference between compilation and run-time environment, the native library being called is AWS kinesis, how can I solve this ?

Comment: If you have built the program with `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21`, you will have to point to it at run time : `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[path-to-new-libstdc++.so.6]:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating an instance similar to the one used by lambda

Public Amazon Linux AMI version (AMI name: amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2

then I had to compile the library again using source 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp
on that instance again, it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently changed your build environment (I was building in Docker and changed the version of the base image to better match the AWS Lambda environment) then remember to do a `make clean` or similar to ensure all the files get rebuilt after this change.  Otherwise some of the compiled files from the previous environment will be reused and this can result in the same error.

In the worst case, remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again, if `npm rebuild` hasn't worked.